# Using ADB to launch an activity while using putExtra

Tags: java, android, android-intent, adb

I've been trying to use the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/shell.html) to determine how to start an activity with putExtra. My putExtra value is of type String and I've tried numerous combinations of "true", "1", putting the string in quotes. I've tried switching the flags to "-n", "-a", etc... Can somebody point out what I'm doing wrong here? I've ready many other articles but they are usually for some built in intent. I'm starting my own custom intent.

*Starting an intent with a string key.*

```
-e|--es <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE>
Add string data as a key-value pair.
--esn <EXTRA_KEY>
Add a null extra. This option is not supported for URI intents.
```

Specifications for

```
-a <ACTION>
Specify the intent action, such as "android.intent.action.VIEW". You can declare this only once.
-n <COMPONENT>
Specify the component name with package name prefix to create an explicit intent, such as "com.example.app/.ExampleActivity".
-f <FLAGS>
Add flags to the intent, as supported by setFlags().
```

**Java**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PrepareDeviceTestActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(PrepareDeviceFragment.MANUAL_CALIBRATE, true);
    startActivity(intent);
```

**ADB**

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT --es calibrate true -n com.package.name/.ui.PrepareDeviceTestActivity
```

and

```
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/.ui.PrepareDeviceTestActivity --es calibrate true
```

Comment: What's happening when you try what you have?

Comment: show your `.getExtras()` code. according the java code you posted your extra is of boolean type

Comment: I figured it out! **adb shell 'am start -n com.package.name/.ui.PrepareDeviceTestActivity --ez "calibrate" true'**