# How to fill 'TO' field when sending an email via adb shell?

Tags: email, android-intent, adb

I'm trying to send an email via adb shell.
my command is:

```
adb shell -a android.intent.action.SEND --es android.intent.extra.SUBJECT 'important!' --es android.intent.extra.TEXT 'hi everyone...' --es android.intent.extra.EMAIL 'rrr@bbb.co'
```

when running this command, a new email window indeed opened and the fields 'body' (TEXT) and 'subject' (SUBJECT) are full. but the field 'To:' is empty.
maybe something with that the type of 'subject' and 'body' fields is: android.widget.EditText and 'To:' is: android.widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView

Comment: is it correct the adb command you posted? maybe `adb shell am broadcast`...?

Comment: no. my command is good, except it has in the end also: '-n package_name' which says what activity to open

Comment: which Android API are you using?

Comment: no one. I am using adb shell, with built-in android intents.

Answer (score 0):

ok after few days searching the internt (I posted this question when I was realy despirated) I found a solution, tnx to
[Using ADB to launch an activity while using putExtra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040166/using-adb-to-launch-an-activity-while-using-putextra)

just use the option '-d rrr@bbb.co' and it will be fine!